# Laravel: Sort a column ASC but 0 come last

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, sql-order-by

Using Laravel, to order by a column ascending, but 0 to come last. This is how we do in normal SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY your_field = 0, your_field;
```

I want to know how to do in Laravel.

Many thanks

Comment: Have you try use `DB::raw` ?

Answer (score 3):

Use `orderByRaw()`

Assuming `Your_Table` model

`Your_Table::orderByRaw('your_field = 0, your_field')->get();`

Answer (score 1):

You can try orderByRaw function.

for example :

```
$data = new YourModel();
$data = $data->orderByRaw('your_field = 0', 'ASC', 'your_field')->get();
```

Comment: I think your code doesn't sort the integer properly. It should be like this:

    `$data = new YourModel();`
    `$data = $data->orderByRaw('your_field = 0, your_field ASC')->get();`

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use `DB::raw`, so the usage maybe.

```
DB::select( DB::raw( "SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY your_field = 0, your_field" ) );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do Laravel has build in query for this?

Comment: Yes sure, you can check this documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions)

Comment: Thank you for sharing the documentation. I'm looking for a solution that doesn't use RAW. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
return $this->your_model
            ->orderByRaw('display_order = 0, display_order ASC')
            ->get();
```

Comment: Provide the comment regarding your answer, That'll help.

Comment: we can use "orderByRaw" which will provide data asc order with data with order_display end of record.